# Postfix relay through Mailgun not recieved in GMail

Tags: postfix

I've set up an Postfix server to relay email through Mailgun to Gmail. It took some puzzling by I managed to have e-mail from my workmail get relayed through postfix to Gmail once. However, subsequent tests are not received.

Postfix logs shows receiving and sending the email (as far as I can make out..).

```
 postfix/smtpd[4395]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-eopbgr70112.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.7.112]: TLSv1.2 with cipher *XXXXX* (256/256 bits)

 postfix/smtpd[4395]: 921897F723: client=mail-eopbgr70112.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.7.112]

 postfix/cleanup[4400]: 921897F723: message-id=<XXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXXXX.com>

 postfix/qmgr[4390]: 921897F723: from=<my@work.com>, size=17184, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

 postfix/local[4401]: 921897F723: to=<mail@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.16, delays=0.16/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)

 postfix/qmgr[4390]: 921897F723: removed
```

As I have almost no knowledge I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to solve this.

(This limited knowledge has also made it difficult to interpret solutions to comparable problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postfix/local` with `relay=local` and `(delivered to mailbox)` clearly shows the message was delivered locally i.e. to a mailbox on the local system. It was not relayed to a next-hop destination.